# How to sume datetime.time values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
A       B
x    00:11:12
y    00:10:10
z    00:00:15
g    00:01:32
```

I would like to be able to simply `sum` column `B`.
However
`df['B'].sum()` yields the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

So then I tried converting those values to timedelta, but I get the follwing error:

`pd.to_timedelta(df["B"])`

```
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>
```

Any idea how can I sum the values from my dataframe? The result should be simply 00:23:09 .

Answer (score 1):

You are close, need casting times to strings:

```
out = pd.to_timedelta(df["B"].astype(str)).sum()
print (out)
0 days 00:23:09
```

If need extract times (days are not important):

```
time = (datetime.datetime.min + out).time()
print (time)
00:23:09
```

---

```
out = pd.Timedelta('3 days 00:23:09')

time = (datetime.datetime.min + out).time()
print (time)
00:23:09
```